# Hashcode implementation double precision

Tags: c#, floating-point, precision, hashcode

I've asked a question about this class before, but here is one again.

I've created a Complex class:

```
 public class Complex
 {
        public double Real { get; set; }
        public double Imaginary { get; set; }
 }
```

And I'm implementing the `Equals` and the `Hashcode` functions, and the Equal function takes in account a certain precision. I use  the following logic for that:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        //Some default null checkint etc here, the next code is all that matters.
        return Math.Abs(complex.Imaginary - Imaginary) <= 0.00001 &&
            Math.Abs(complex.Real - Real)  <= 0.00001;
    }
```

Well this works, when the Imaginary and the Real part are really close to each other, it says they are the same.

Now I was trying to implement the HashCode function, I've used some examples John skeet used here, currently I have the following.

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hash = 17;
        hash = hash*23 + Real.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash*23 + Imaginary.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
```

However, this does not take in account the certain precision I want to use. So basically the following two classes:

`Complex1[Real = 1.123456; Imaginary = 1.123456]`

`Complex2[Real = 1.123457; Imaginary = 1.123457]`

Are `Equal` but do not provide the same `HashCode`, how can I achieve that?

Comment: It is generally considered bad to have a HashCode that will change as the object changes.  What you might want to consider is doing this as a struct instead of a class and make the properties read-only so that the values don't change and if they do then a new object is created.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I kinda figured what I was doing was considered bad practice. But what's the advantage of making it a struct and if the values change, creating a new object?

Comment: You're trying to redefine Equals and HashCode, there is not gonna be a happy end here.

Comment: Henk, I use the it as following:

`Complex c = new Complex(100,200);`
`Complex c2 = Complex.FromPolar(c.Argument, c. Magnitude);`

(I have not described the `c2` functions/properties, but they are just basic complex number things.

Now, mathematically those two complex numbers are exactly the same, yet programmatic they are not (they are not `Equal`)

Comment: @Henk: nothing wrong with redefining Equals and HashCode as long as you adher to their contact. Unfortunately, this implementation doesn't (and can't).

Comment: @Timo: I can't remember if there is a specific reason to using a struct vs a class.  I just tend to use a struct for immutable data types.  The reason you don't want to modify the the values though once it is created is if you have it in a container that depends on the HashCode and you change the object which causes a new HashCode to be created then you will run into other problems as the container is using the HashCode as a sort of contract and doesn't expect the HashCode to change once it is defined by the object.

Comment: Timo, Equality is hard enough for simple double values (reals). You're compounding it. And read all of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your `Equals()` implementation is broken. Read [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) to see why.

Second, such a "fuzzy equals" breaks the contract of `Equals()` (it's not transitive, for one thing), so **using it with `Hashtable` will not work**, no matter how you implement `GetHashCode()`.

For this kind of thing, you really need a spatial index such as an [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

Comment: An R-Tree is a bit strange to think about for this problem, since the size of each bin depends on the spatial density of objects in that region.  For many applications, a density-independent index like a grid would make more sense, and be far easier to implement (note that a quad-tree would be overkill if we don't need neighborhood lookups).  A R-Tree has the advantage, though, of using more significant digits to compare objects in regions of the space that have high density.

Answer (score 2):

Just drop precision when you calculate the hash value.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    var hash = 17;
    hash = hash*23 + Math.Round(Real, 5).GetHashCode();
    hash = hash*23 + Math.Round(Imaginary, 5).GetHashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

where `5` is you precision value

Answer (score 1):

I see two simple options:

- Use Decimal instead of double
- Instead of using Real.GetHashCode, use Real.RoundTo6Ciphers().GetHashCode().

Then you'll have the same hashcode.

Comment: I think using Decimal instead of double is kinda an overkill for such a basic class. It should preferable be super fast :D

And yeah, that's a good idea, using `Real.RoundTo6Ciphers().GetHashCode()`

Comment: Decimal won't help when he wants to have equality under coordinate transformations. And rounding won't help when he wants Hashtable to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would create read-only properties that round Real and Imaginary to the nearest hundred-thousandth and then do equals and hashcode implementations on those getter properties.