# Unit testing class with doubles

Tags: c#, unit-testing, floating-accuracy

I have a class that contains (one or more...) doubles. For example:

```
public class TestFloatClass{
 public double Double1{get;set;}
 public double Double2{get;set;}

 public void SetDoubleByCalculation(double value){
  Double1 = //Some calculations here;
  Double2 = //Some calculations here;
 } 
}
```

I want to test the `SetDoubleByCalculation(double value)` method, so I start writing unit tests.

```
TestFloatClass expected = new TestFloatClass();
expected.Double1 = 100.10;
expected.Double2 = 200.24554;

TestFloatClass actual = new TestFloatClass();
actual.SetDoubleByCalculation(Math.PI); //Just using something random here.
```

In this case, `expected.Double1` and `actual.Double1` are approximately the same. But not exactly due to floating point accuracy.

However, I'm not sure how to unit test this correctly. These are the things I have tried so far.

**Including a certain delta in the equals operator**

My first intuition said, well, just include the logic in the equals operator like so:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj){
  return Math.Abs(this.Double1 - obj.Double1) <= 0.00001 &&
              Math.Abs(this.Double1 - obj.Double1)  <= 0.00001; 
}
```

But as said in this [Hashcode implementation double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703602/hashcode-implementation-double-precision) topic, it's just practice to do so.

**Just using the Assert override**

I can go on by testing it as follows:

```
Assert.Equals(expected.Double1, actual.Double1, 0.0000001); //Or just some precision
Assert.Equals(expected.Double2, acutal.Double2, 0.0000001);
```

But then again, then I have to do this for EVERY property in this class. If the `TestFloatClass` also had two properties `VeryComplicatedClass vcc` & `int integer` then I'd have to add those too.

```
Assert.Equals(expected.Double1, actual.Double1, 0.0000001); //Or just some precision
Assert.Equals(expected.Double2, actual.Double2, 0.0000001);
Assert.Equals(expected.vcc, actual.vcc);
Assert.Equals(expected.integer, actual.integer);
```

And it would keep growing if the class gets bigger...

**So my question**

What is the best way to test this class?

Comment: I would definitely recommend using your Assert override example in preference to overriding Equals. Can you explain your reservations with respect to adding an Assert to check every property in a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should split the tests:

```
Assert.Equals(expected.Double2, acutal.Double2, 0.0000001);
Assert.Equals(expected.vcc, actual.vcc);
```

Make (separate) unit Tests for  the Double2 and vcc properties on the class of actual/expected.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Because well, what if `TestFloatClass` has like 20 double values, would I have to create 20 separate unit tests? Also, how is it differently then just writing them below each other?

Comment: I mean that when testing a double property, actual and expected should be of type double.

Comment: @TimoWillemsen Writing them in separate unit tests will allow you to see which one failed. Testing is not about the values each variable can have, you want to test the functions they use.

Answer (score 1):

Note that my response to your other question mainly criticized the use of a thusly modified `Equals()` together with `GetHashCode()` for use in a `Hashtable` - that just won't work, which is a good example why it's problematic to override `Equals()` in a way that breaks its contract. If you only use it for direct comparisons in tests, that would be OK. But it might be a better idea to have a *separate* comparison method (perhaps called `FuzzyEquals()`) for use in tests to avoid confusion.

Additionally, comparing with a fixed epsilon is problematic if your values can be very small or very large - read [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) for details .

Comment: Yeah I've read your very carefully. And also the website you've linked to. Thanks a lot for that :) However, I'm not really fond of changing my class just so I can test it. Perhaps it's just better to write an Equals method in the test project? Anyhow, thanks a lot for all your trouble helping me :)